# What happens if MySQL has not enough space for temp tables?

Tags: mysql

Since a litle while (maybe two weeks) the MySQL 5.5 get stucked from time to time. That means that the server load get incredibly high, all queries gets frozen and the #connections reaches the limit. I need to restart the MySQL Server to solve this.

Maybe this is just a deadlock but since nothing changed in the application logic I do not think so.
I wonder what happens if there is not enough disk space left to fill a temp table. This could be a problem on this server. The documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/full-disk.html says that there will be a *no space left on device* error message, but I didnt found this on the mysql-error.log. Will this message also reported for temp tables?

In the slow-query.log I found this:

```
# Query_time: 61229.230881  Lock_time: 0.000183 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 193600429837
```

For this query there is a big temp table needed. I'm not sure if this was before or after I restart the MySQL Server. I only know that this was during the last problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about disk space, if this was the problem, MySQL would let you know.

A query that needs to examine 193600429837 rows is likely to complete within a decade or two. Unfortunately, your server is strong enough to support this volume, and vailiantly tries its best to fulfil the query.

Rewrite the offending query, or try to add an index or two (see also: [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html)).